# Change keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Excel 2016 in Windows

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016, I would like to change the keyboard shortcut for the Search command from <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> so that this command has the same keyboard shortcut as in other programs. However, I could not find how to do this.

In Word, to do this, I can right click on the ribbon, select "Customize ribbon" and click on the button "Keyboard shortcuts: Customize" like in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot from word]

However, in Excel, this button doesn't exist, or at least I couldn't find it:

[image: screenshot form excel with missing button]

I found a similar issue with Excel in Mac [here](https://superuser.com/questions/955060/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-in-excel-2016-for-mac), but it didn't help me since the answers suggested using features that are specific for Mac and I'm using Windows.

How can I change keyboard shortcuts in Excel 2016 in Windows?

Comment: @teylyn No, that's about Excel 2010 and my question is about Excel 2016. They're very similar, but the answers in the other question didn't work for me.

Comment: It is a duplicate. Excel does not have the option to customize keyboard shortcuts. This goes for 2010 and all later versions. The only approach is to use macros to do the thing you want to do and assign your desired KB shortcut to the macro.